# Correct way to get value of namespace declaration attribute

Tags: javascript, xml, namespaces, svg

Consider this SVG/XML and JavaScript:

```
<svg id="foo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <use id="bar" xlink:href="#whee" />
</svg>
...
var foo  = document.getElementById('foo');
var bar  = document.getElementById('bar');
var xlnk = foo...; // What is correct here?
var link = bar.getAttributeNS(xlnk,'href');
```

Clearly I can make this work with `xlnk = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`; my question, however, is what is the correct way to dynamically fetch the `xmlns:xlink` attribute on the `svg` element?

The following code happens to work in Safari/Chrome/FF, but is it really valid?
`var xlnk = foo.getAttribute('xmlns:xlink');`

The following code returns an empty string in those browsers:
`var xlnk = foo.getAttributeNS( "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "xlink" );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`getAttributeNS()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-ElGetAttrNS) specification documents the second parameter as:

> "The [local name](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#dt-localname) of the attribute to retrieve."

Per [Namespaces in XML, 3rd Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) the `xmlns` prefix is [reserved](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#xmlReserved) and used as part of the [`PrefixedAttName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl) to define an `NSAttName`.

Since a `NSAttName` does not have a "local part"—and a [`QName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-qualnames) does—it seems that `xmlns:xlink` is not considered a namespace+local name, but is rather the attribute name itself. As this is consistent with the experimental results across normally-standards-compliant browsers, I am convinced that the following code is valid and correct:

```
var xlnk = foo.getAttribute('xmlns:xlink');
```